# A redirect page after login Correct in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

With this simple php script after login, configure a hyperlink to page http://www.mysite.it 
how can I change the script so that if the login is correct, you directly open the link http://www.mysite.it

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pw'];

if($username == "" or $password == ""){
echo "Non puoi accedere senza Username o password";
}else if($username == "" and $password == ""){
echo "Non puoi accedere senza Username e password";
}else{
// configure your username and password
if($username == "test" AND $password == "test"){
echo "Benvenuto $username";
echo "<a href='http://www.mysite.it'>Vai alla pagina</a>";
}else{
echo "Accesso negato, questo username non esiste";
}
}

function loggeduser($username){

}


?>
```

Comment: You need to use header redirect and its explained very well here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to do a redirection:

```
function redirectTo($newUrl)  
{ 
      header("Location: " . $newUrl);
      exit();
}
```

and in your code:

```
if($username == "test" AND $password == "test"){
   redirectTo("http://www.mysite.it");    
}else{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Header must be declared first on page. Or it will show error like headers already declared.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "www.xyz.com"
      </script>';
```

Use this instead.